# MSword file attachment not working in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, email, attachment

I am using codeigniter and I am trying to send an email with an attachment, It is working well when i upload pdf but if i upload word file, i receive an empty email, although I have checked the uploading of word file is successful as well, all the uploaded files are in the given path. But there is nothing in email in MSword file case. Here is my code:

```
//My email function in controller
$attachment = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$this->email->attach('uploads/enquiry/'.$attachment);
```

Comment: can your check your file is upload `echo 'uploads/enquiry/'.$attachment;` path and see you got correct file path

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide full path of the file.

so instead of

```
$this->email->attach('uploads/enquiry/'.$attachment);
```

try something like this

```
$this->email->attach(FCPATH.'/uploads/enquiry/'.$attachment);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way, 
You will surely get answer :-

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html